# Ignore null values when destructuring in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

In Serilog, is it possible to ignore properties when their values are null?

I've tried add DataMember attributes but these seem to be ignored:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Further looking into the source I've noticed there's an [AttributedDestructuringPolicy](https://github.com/destructurama/attributed/blob/master/src/Destructurama.Attributed/Attributed/AttributedDestructuringPolicy.cs) but this seems to control rendering property values rather than omitting properties.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a great addition to `AttributedDestructuringPolicy` - I don't think there's anything built-in to enable it currently however.